# The method setButton is ambiguous on AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this method:

```
alert.setButton(1, "OK", null);
```

but it doesn't work, because I got this alert on my sdk:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The method setButton(int, CharSequence, Message) is ambiguous for the type AlertDialog (...)

How to resolve that?
THanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't hardcode `1`, there are some constants in class [`DialogInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html): [`BUTTON_NEGATIVE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_NEGATIVE), [`BUTTON_NEUTRAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_NEUTRAL), [`BUTTON_POSITIVE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_POSITIVE)…

And, there are overloaded methods:

- [`setButton(int whichButton, CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29)
- [`setButton(int whichButton, CharSequence text, Message msg)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Message%29)

You passed `null` to the third parameter, so the compiler didn't know which method you wanted to use.

Comment: Ok, I have something like this: `alert.setButton(-3, cs, new OnClickListener(){});` How to write the third parameter correct?

Comment: @Toledo You can cast a type to `null` instead of creating new redundant object, e.g.: `setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Hello World", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);`

Comment: can't pass null is actually ambiguous!